# Is it possible to create table templates in Filemaker?

Tags: filemaker

I'm using Filemaker Pro 12 and I was wondering if there is a way of creating a template for tables.  There are a number of fields I'm placing in my tables that are identical utility-fields like modification time-stamp, active/inactive flags, etc.  I was hoping there was a way that I could define the skeleton of each table somehow instead of having to manually add these identical fields every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the Advanced version, you can copy&paste fields among tables/files.

Using the regular version, you can import records from your "default" table and specify [New Table...] as the target table. This will recreate the source table's structure in the target file. The source table does not have to contain any records for this to work.

Comment: I will try this when I'm back in the office.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To expand a little bit on [michael-hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k)'s answer, if you're using FileMaker Pro Advanced, a good practice is to create a "Default" table that has your core utility fields.  When you want to make a new table in Manage Database, instead:

1. Highlight the Default table,
2. Copy & Paste the table, then
3. Rename the new table.